# How query execution time and concurrent users affect DTU

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am using Azure SQL database. In Azure, pricing is calculated on the basics of `DTU` (**Database Throughput Unit**). There are lots of articles and QA regarding this but I failed to find the **Steps for calculation of DTU** or **what are the factors affecting DTU**. If I know the calculation steps, I can make changes in my codes or queries so that I can utilize the resource in a good manner.

Whether the following factors are affecting DTU?

1. Volume of data in the DB
2. Volume of data that we are fetching;
3. Type of joins?
4. Concurrent users/Hits

Azure Pricing Table:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, the concept of DTUs is deliberately a bit vague. From the same page the graphic in the question came from:

[SQL Database service tiers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-service-tiers/)

> #### Understanding DTUs
>
> The Database Throughput Unit (DTU) is the unit of measure in SQL Database that represents the relative power of a database to process transactions given the constraints of the hardware driving the database. DTU is a concept similar to horsepower in a car. It describes the relative performance of one database to another. Just like with horsepower in a car, the more DTU a database has, the more power it has. Horsepower is a function of many different factors: weight, engine capacity, turbo, exhaust system. Similarly, DTU is a function of the amount and type of **memory, compute, and disk** the database can consume. You can read the details of how we determine DTU in the [Benchmark Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn741327.aspx)).

(emphasis added)

There are more details about how to monitor your usage and decide on an appropriate tier in the links above, the rest of the official documentation, and the [Azure SQL Database blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2014/05/05/azure-sql-database-service-tiers-amp-performance-q-amp-a.aspx).